# Wordpress 3 - Remove Links from Posts via functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there a way that I can remove links in posts via my functions.php file. Basically I don't want anyone to be able to go outside of the blog posts that are viewed. I have hundreds of posts so I obviously can't go through all of them and remove them manually. Or could I use javascript?

Thanks so much.

---

**Updated:** The jQuery below is great. Does anyone know if there is a way I can do it thru php in my functions.php file? If, for whatever ridiculous reason, someone has JS disabled is why I ask.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use JavaScript, but you're not going to be able to stop people leaving if they want to.

Something like this may work, although I haven't tested and it was written off-hand:

```
<script>
$('#content a').each(function() {
    $(this).replaceWith($(this).text());
});
</script>
```

With the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) library, this *should* replace all `<a>` tags with what was in between them.

So `<a href="http://www.google.co.uk/">Google</a>` should become just `Google`.

Answer (score 2):

You can strip out the links on the fly using a regular expression -

```
$post_content = get_the_content();
$post_content = preg_replace( "|<a *href=\"(.*)\">(.*)</a>|", "\\2", $post_content );
echo $post_content
```

This would need to go in your theme wherever you print the_content. Untested.

Comment: Thanks. I think I'll end up going with the jquery route cause this removed all formatting, breaks and any plugin/shortcode stuff.